# web3.eth.getTransaction("txh") search algorithm

Tags: go-ethereum

`web3.eth.getTransaction("txh")` , is this call searches the entire blockchain data or  is there an indexing ?

Answer (score 0):

Eth will not search transactions using linear search but it will use the Merkle tree(Merkle Patricia Tree).

Merkle trees are a fundamental part of what makes blockchains tick. Although it is definitely theoretically possible to make a blockchain without Merkle trees, simply by creating giant block headers that directly contain every transaction, doing so poses large scalability challenges that arguably puts the ability to trustlessly use blockchains out of the reach of all but the most powerful computers in the long term.

For more details please check below link:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree